# Dependency Injection is preventing client side validation MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject, autofac

I'm trying to apply dependency injection with `Autofac` or `Ninject`, but I end up with client side validation not working.

Here is my interface:

```
     public interface IPersonRepository
{
    IQueryable<Person> Persons { get; }
}
```

And here is the model:

```
     class EFPersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    public EFPersonRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return _context.Persons; }
    }
}
```

And here is the controller:

```
    public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository;



    public PersonController(IPersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var person=new Person();
        return View(person);
    }
    }
```

Application start:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
      //  ApplyDependeny();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    private void ApplyDependeny()
    {
        var context = new Context();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterModule(new DependencyInjector(context));
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder.Build()));
    }
```

The client side references:

```
     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

web.config:

```
     <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

But the validation is not working.

Comment: Why do say that it's the IOC container that prevents client side validation?

Comment: @jgauffin: It would seem to be a guess, and most likely an incorrect one.

Comment: Then remove the guess and you'll probably get better help. Also add any javascript errors and how the generated view looks like.

Comment: after removing the functionality of dependency injection container validation works perfectly ! so it's the dependency injection , what I guess is that I'm missing something with autofac that makes the validation works with autofac or Ninject what exactly that's what I'm asking for

Answer (score 0):

add this client side references

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I have commented the  ApplyDependeny() method and worked without the dependency and the validation works very well

Comment: try `var context =  new FormContext()`

Comment: where to use this? I'm new to dependency injection

Comment: in `applydepedency` method, I am not  sure this will work or not. One thing i am sure your views are not generating the tags(unobtrusive) that jQuery use to perform client side validation, and thats happening because of context.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering your context and all your controllers but you forgot to register your Repository.

```
 builder.RegisterType<EFPersonRepository>().As<IPersonRepository>();
```

Comment: I did but nothing changed , there must be something missing

Comment: Change  builder.RegisterModule(new DependencyInjector(context)); to builder.RegisterType<Context>();